# Get form name using javascript

Tags: javascript

How to get the form name when peress a button inside the form ? `document.forms[0].name` will do the job only if i have one form. How about for multiple forms ?

FORM:

```
<form name="aaa">
<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit Form"  onclick="somefunction();">
</form>
```

FUNCTION:

```
<script>
function somefunction()
{
var thename=document.forms[0].name;
alert (thename);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the below

```
var thename=document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].name;
```

(or)

```
var thename = document.forms[0].name;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6844R/3/)

Comment: Yes, that solve half of the issue, however in that way i can`t use more than one form in the page becouse the function will return the first form allways!

Comment: that should be a different question though ;)